# Android onClickListener action do not show this message again

Tags: android, button, android-activity, onclicklistener

[This is the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbn8E.jpg)

Here is the code

```
public class PraiseColleagueHelpScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
private Object view;

TextView okButton ;
TextView dontButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_praise_colleague_help_screen);
    okButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
    dontButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dont_show_message_again);
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, PraiseColleaguePickerActivity.class);

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    dontButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on the OK button it opens a db with a list of colleagues

My question is what to insert in the `

```
dontButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });`
```

so when I click on the Don't show this message again, it still opens the db with colleagues but I do not see the view on the next load.

Comment: You have to start different activity on that button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use sharePreferences or SQLite to save user's settings.

For example , if the user does not want to be shown the message again , you can store the value in shared preferences and the next time he clicks, you can check the shared preferences and show or not show based on the value.